# Export UDDT definitions from SQL Server 6.5 to XML

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to write a script to pull a database from old MS SQL 6.5
I stumbled at retrieving the user types

I have following custom types :

[image]

I wrote a simple script, where a base name looked up from withing same table:

```
select t1.name as name, t2.name as base_name, t1.length as length 
from systypes t1, systypes t2 
where t1.usertype > 100 and t2.usertype <= 100 and t1.type = t2.type
```

It returns me following result:

```
name                           base_name                      length 
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------ 
bitZ                           bit                            1      
tinyintZ                       tinyint                        1      
smallintZ                      smallint                       2      
intZ                           int                            4      
smalldatetimeZ                 smalldatetime                  4      
charZ_254                      sysname                        254    
charZ_254                      varchar                        254    
charZ_80                       sysname                        80     
charZ_80                       varchar                        80     
charZ_50                       sysname                        50     
charZ_50                       varchar                        50     
charZ_40                       sysname                        40     
charZ_40                       varchar                        40     
charZ_35                       sysname                        35     
charZ_35                       varchar                        35     
charZ_30                       sysname                        30     
charZ_30                       varchar                        30     
charZ_20                       sysname                        20     
charZ_20                       varchar                        20     
charZ_16                       sysname                        16     
charZ_16                       varchar                        16     
charZ_14                       sysname                        14     
charZ_14                       varchar                        14     
charZ_12                       sysname                        12     
charZ_12                       varchar                        12     
charZ_10                       sysname                        10     
charZ_10                       varchar                        10     
charZ_8                        sysname                        8      
charZ_8                        varchar                        8      
charZ_5                        sysname                        5      
charZ_5                        varchar                        5      
charZ_4                        sysname                        4      
charZ_4                        varchar                        4      
charZ_1                        sysname                        1      
charZ_1                        varchar                        1      
charZ_120                      sysname                        120    
charZ_120                      varchar                        120    
binZ_10                        binary                         10     
binZ_10                        timestamp                      10
```

Here are 2 problems:

1. varchar resolved to two types, sysname and varchar because they have the same base type. Same problem for binZ_10
2. Non var char returned as non-zero length

Which script can I use to get a proper, MS output?

Here is a fragment of original table:

select type, name from systypes
order by type

```
type name                           
---- ------------------------------ 
. . .                  
39   charZ_80                       
39   sysname                        
39   varchar                        
45   binary                         
45   binZ_10                        
45   timestamp                      
47   char     
. . .
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question really is: what is a "proper, MS output"? Are you trying to generate [`CREATE TYPE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007(v=sql.100).aspx) statements to use in a newer version of SQL Server?

Comment: I want to get the same info what I see in management studio to output it to .xml. Actually, I realized I could use SQL trace for this, I will try as soon as I have access to my home system

Comment: Converting query results to XML is usually fairly easy, even if you have to just save them to a file and then transform the file using a script in your preferred language (since 6.5 has no native XML support). If you need help with this, it would be good to be as specific as possible about what difficulties you have.

Comment: Thanks, coming from the world of NoSQL, SQL is a new for me. But once data is out on Java side I feel like fish in water

Answer (score 0):

I used a trace, result is returned by sp_MShelptype.

I need a subset of fields, so I pushed the result into temp table:

```
create table #Result
(
    UserDatatypeName varchar(92), owner varchar(20), basetypename varchar(92), defaultname varchar(61), rulename varchar(61) null, tid int, length int, nullable int, dt_prec int null, dt_scale int null, dt_flags int, allowidentity int
)

insert #Result exec sp_MShelptype null, 'uddt'

select UserDatatypeName name, basetypename base_type, length, defaultname default from #Result

drop table #Result
```